# ejabberd mod_push and mod_push_keepalive does not start

Tags: push, ejabberd

I run a ejabberd 16.09 server on Debian Stretch. When I enable the modules mod_push and/or mod_push_keepalive the server doesn´t start and the log file tells:

```
2019-03-15 11:16:03.535 [critical] <0.61.0>@gen_mod:start_module:162 Problem starting the module mod_push for host <<"jabber.mydomain.de">> 
options: []
error: undef
[{mod_push,start,[<<"jabber.mydomain.de">>,[]],[]},
{gen_mod,start_module,3,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{line,154}]},
{lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1338}]},
{ejabberd_app,start,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_app.erl"},{line,77}]},
{application_master,start_it_old,4,
[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,273}]}]
2019-03-15 11:19:54.048 [critical] <0.61.0>@gen_mod:maybe_halt_ejabberd:170 ejabberd initialization was aborted because a module start failed.
```

Does anybody have a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, you won't find any mod_push file in your installation, because mod_push was first included in ejabberd 17.08 https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/d6f1d3df5b5a75f618bcc6eeb6425bc47dfd84d2